# Meaning of this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a question from a book.

> First we subtract these two vectors
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbf{r}&=x\hat{e}_x+y\hat{e}_y+z\hat{e}_z\\
> \mathbf{r'}&=x'\hat{e}_x+y'\hat{e}_y+z'\hat{e}_z
> \end{align}
>   so we get
>   $$
> \mathbf{R}=\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}=(x-x')\hat{e}_x+(y-y')\hat{e}_y+(z-z')\hat{e}_z
> $$
>   Now, let $f$ be a scalar function of $\mathbf{R}$, such that $f(\mathbf{R})$.

$f$ is a multivariable function, right? But of which variables?

Does it mean $f(\mathbf{R})=f(x,y,z)$?

Or $f(\mathbf{R})=f(x',y',z')$?

Or maybe $f(\mathbf{R})=f(x,x',y,y',z,z')$?

Comment: It should say $f(\mathbb{R}) =$ something. Otherwise it's not a complete sentence.  Anyway in this case it would be a function of three variables: $x-x'$, $y-y'$, and $z-z'$.

Comment: I mean, it could be. Is there any other context from the book, or is that the whole problem as stated by the book? In any case, it would be a scalar function that takes vectors as its input.

Comment: your conclusion from the information given that it must be a scalar function is just wrong.

Comment: @Max I updated my post.

Comment: $\mathbf R$ is a function of $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r'$, or of $x, y, z, x', y', z'$, whichever you prefer. It's common, especially in physics, to not be explicit with such "obvious" things but to leave it open so that any variable in an expression can be seen as an argument of a function.

Comment: @Max : Drew from context. Usually vector valued functions would have denoted $f$ in a different font type. I only see "f" in the way the OP stated it in terms of scalar functions. You're right. Given the original context, there wasn't enough info to draw that certainly, but given the fact that the problem uses that classic $\mathbf{R}$ that's constantly in Physics, I figured it was safe to jump to that conclusion.